# How do I limit a condition to a subset of data in a CASE when grouping?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Assuming the table:

```
| ID | Customer | Agent    | Event     | Date       |
|====|==========|==========|===========|============|
| 01 | Steve    | Jerry    | Booked    | 2019-01-01 |
| 02 | Steve    | Jerry    | Canceled  | 2019-01-13 |
| 03 | Steve    | Rusty    | Booked    | 2019-01-16 |
| 04 | Carla    | JSnow    | Booked    | 2019-01-04 |
| 05 | Carla    | JSnow    | Resched   | 2019-01-16 |
```

I have a query that groups a list of events into their owners, detects the first Booking Date, and notes the Agent for the first booking:

```
SELECT 
    Customer,
    FIRST_VALUE(Agent),
    MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 'Booked' THEN Date END) as BookDate,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 'Canceled' THEN Date END) as CancelDate
FROM Events
GROUP BY Customer

// produces:
| Customer | Agent    | BookDate   | CancelDate |
|==========|==========|============|============|
| Steve    | Jerry    | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-13 |
| Carla    | JSnow    | 2019-01-04 | NULL       |
```

I'm trying to add a "Booking Agent After Cancel" column so that it looks like this:

```
| Customer | Agent    | BookDate   | CancelDate | Agent2   |
|==========|==========|============|============|==========|
| Steve    | Jerry    | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-13 | Rusty    |
| Carla    | JSnow    | 2019-01-04 | NULL       | NULL     |
```

I can't figure out how to limit the aggregate for the agent name to only include events where the 'Booked' date is past the 'Canceled' date (if it exists).

Comment: Can you add your expected output as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do this with just aggregation.  But adding a `LAG()` to the subquery gives you the information you need:

```
SELECT Customer, FIRST_VALUE(Agent),
       MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 'Booked' THEN Date END) as BookDate,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 'Canceled' THEN Date END) as CancelDate,
       MIN(CASE WHEN prev_event = 'Canceled' THEN Agent END) as Agent2
FROM (SELECT e.*, 
             LAG(Event) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Date) as prev_event
      FROM Events e
     ) e
GROUP BY Customer;
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I ended up using LEAD instead of LAG, but the solution worked. Note that this approach does require 100% table scanning on each iteration in Snowflake and nothing gets cached and can take a little longer.